# Android - find nearby places

Tags: android, geolocation

Developing an App on Android.
Looking for a free REST API that returns in XML format nearby places (Just like Facebook places app on iphone does).
Ultimately I would also want to display some of the places returned on the MapActivity - so better to have longitude-latitute in response. I also want to store the result address in free form, so that should also be part of the response..

I also want some other API - which give free-format address would convert it to longitude-latitude. Something like this:
http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Foursquare's API to get near by venues. You get the GPS location on the phone and then use Foursquare to get a list of venues.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Foursquare's, Yelp and Google Places. Does it have to be XML, I am not sure if Yelp does XML, their default is JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Amir and user317819.. I checked Foursquare as per the link mentioned here:
http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/wiki/FoursquareIntents

[in the post ---> How to invoke Foursquare application from my app in Android phone?

however, the urls in that app show options of opening with Foursquare app or Browser. Is there a way to get only the raw data back, which I can use in my own app? Like in xml format or so..?

Comment: I found what I needed here: http://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/web/api-documentation.. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Amir - sure - I tried, but doesn't allow me due to the min. threshold req.